# How to grep this kind of pattern out using this "grep" command?

Tags: bash, grep

In file named appleFile:

```
1.apple_with_seeds###
2.apple_with_seeds###
3.apple_with_seeds_and_skins###
4.apple_with_seeds_and_skins###
5.apple_with_seeds_and_skins###
.....
.....
.....
```

How can i use the grep command to grep the pattern only with "apple_with_seeds"???
It is supposed that there is random characters after seeds and skins.

```
Result:
1.apple_with_seeds###
2.apple_with_seeds###
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work for you:

```
grep 'apple_with_seeds[^_]' appleFile
```

That will print all lines having no `_` character after `seeds`. You can add other characters to exclude to between the brackets (but after the `^`), e.g. `[^_a-z]` will additionally exclude all lower case letters.

Or you could explicitly *include* some characters (like `#`):

```
grep 'apple_with_seeds[#]*$' appleFile
```

And again you can add arbitrary characters between the brackets, e.g. `[#A-Z]` would match any of the characters `#` or `A`-`Z`.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat appleFile | grep "apple_with_seeds$"
```

**UPDATE**:
if you want to exclude something, try `-v` option:

```
 cat appleFile | grep "apple_with_seeds$" | grep -v "exclude_pattern"
```

Comment: what about there is characters after the seeds?
Is there any grep command than can grep "patternA" but not in "patternB"?

Comment: cat appleFile | grep "apple_with_seeds$" | grep -v "exclude_pattern"

Comment: Don't use `cat`. See comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cat appleFile|grep -i seeds$
```

Comment: what about there is characters after the seeds?
Is there any grep command than can grep "patternA" but not in "patternB"?

Comment: In that case you can directly `grep 'apple_with_seeds###$'`

Comment: Why is everyone using the `cat` command? There's no need for it. For any command, you can almost always include the filename after the command, or if it's like the `tr` command, you can redirect the file. Using `cat` in this way creates a separate process which can cause problems when you use it in a shell script.

Comment: @David, that's what I do. This is just an example provided.